# How to stretch or shrink background images automatically in css?

Tags: html, css

Hey so I have a bunch of stock images that I am loading as the background image for the homepage of my website.

The problem is that few of them have resolution around 1024 x 768 and few have very high resolution like 1920 x 1024.

Now how do I shrink or stretch my wall papers according to the resolution of my user's screen?

I tried using background-image: cover but incase I load a high resolution image on a low resolution screen only a part of the image is visible on the screen. But it works perfectly in the case of low resolution images being loaded onto high resolution screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ - it should give you all the info you need.

This is the key css:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should shrink or stretch your image:

```
body {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```